# Php is messing up my upload size

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, filesize

This I believe is a PHP issue, but please feel free to chime in. I am trying to upload a file, I have set the max size to 10240 (10mb's). I am trying to upload a file, (in Ubuntu 13.04) from the desktop to my localhost site. This file size is 18.9kb's its a zip. I have checked the size 50 times.

I `var_dump` the file coming in: `$_FILES['file']['size']` to check the size as it's spazzing out through a custom error stating "this file exceeds the allowed size of 10mb's."

The size dumped? **18888** thats roughly 18mb's

Oo.

That's not right, the file I am uploading is 18.9kb's

Is there something I should be looking for? Im not sure how to fix this. I am running `PHP 5.4.latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just used the integer 10240 for [upload_max_filesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize), then it's measured in bytes, so your limit is 10KB, not 10MB

Also be aware that you need to ensure [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) is at least as large as this too, and see [this manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php) for other pitfalls *<sub>(thanks zsawyer)</sub>*.

Comment: +1 for hint at the other pitfall ([here are more hints](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php))